# Upload Photo Failed Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, web

This is my code, my photo can't be inserted into the database.

Actually I want to make an online exam with the codeigniter. I want to upload the question with the pic. but when I tried to upload the pict, the code is not working.

but the question success inserted into the database. only the pict failed to upload

Controller:

```html
function insert(){
  $nama_asli = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $config ['file_name'] = $nama_asli;
  $config ['upload_path'] = './images';
  $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
  $config ['max_size'] = '2500';
   
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   
  $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
  $file_name = $upload_data['file_name']; 
  
  $id_soal = '';
  $soal = $_POST['soal'];
  $a = $_POST['a'];
  $b = $_POST['b'];
  $c = $_POST['c'];
  $d = $_POST['d'];
  $kunci = $_POST['kunci'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];

  $data = array(
   'id_soal' => $id_soal,
   'soal' => $soal,
   'a' => $a,
   'b' => $b,
   'c' => $c,
   'd' => $d,
   'kunci' => $kunci,
   'status' => $status,
   'foto' => $file_name,
   );

  $hasil = $this->soal_model->Simpan('soal', $data);

  if($hasil>=1){
   redirect('dashboard/index', $data);
  }
 }
```

Model:

```html
class Soal_model extends Ci_Model {

  public function Ambil($where= "") {
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from soal '.$where);
    return $data;
  }
  
  public function Simpan($tabel, $data){
    $res = $this->db->insert($tabel, $data);
    return $res;
  }
```

View:

```html
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/insert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" style = "margin : 10px;">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Soal :</label>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="soal" id="soal" required></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban A :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="a" id="a" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban B :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="b" id="b" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban C :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="c" id="c" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban D :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="d" id="d" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Kunci :</label>
  <select name="kunci" id="kunci" class="form-control">
  <option>Select</option> 
  <option>A</option>  
  <option>B</option> 
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  </select> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Status :</label>
  <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="tampil">Tampil</option>  
  <option value="tidak">Tidak</option> 
  </select> 
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Photo :</label>
  <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" size="20"/>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Simpan</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Hapus</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Database:

[image]

Comment: what type of error it returns  ?

Comment: Can you show your html form ?

Comment: i've updated my code. you can check @Saravana Dev

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use this code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('soal_model');
}

function insert()
{
    $config =array(
        'upload_path' => './images',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
        'max_size' => '2500',
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->do_upload('file_upload');

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();   

    $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
    $data = array(
        'foto' => $file_name,
    );

    $hasil = $this->soal_model->Simpan('soal', $data);

    if($hasil>=1){
        redirect('dashboard/index', $data);
    }
}   
?>
```